# Implementation of a set using ArrayList in a generic class

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, set

Im trying to implement a set using arrayList, i want to make 2 constructors. an empty one and one that get an array and adds it:

```
        public class set<E> {
        Set <E> setList;
        ArrayList<E> elementList;

        public set(){

            setList = (Set<E>) new ArrayList();
        }

        public <E> set(E[] inputArray){
            super();
            for(E element: inputArray) // not working
                setList.add( element);
            // setList.addAll(Arrays.asList(inputArray)); - not working either
        }
```

I get an error at the second constructor:

> "The method add(E) at the type set is not applicable for arguments
>   (E)"

Comment: What do you intend to do with `(Set<E>) new ArrayList()`?

Comment: Did you read the warning caused by `<E>` in your constructor declaration ? Remove the `<E>`.

Comment: @arshajii: union, intersct, deletion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `<E>` in the constructor declaration:

```
    public <E> set(E[] inputArray){
           ^^^ Get rid of this
```

As things stand, you are creating a second unrelated generic type parameter called `E` that shadows the `E` in `set<E>`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method `set(E[])` to as follows:

```
public Set(E[] inputArray) {
    super();
    for(E element: inputArray) {
        setList.add(element);
    }
}
```

Reason:

> Type `E` is already generic type created using `Set<E>` and as such, you don't need to redefine `E` in the constructor.